# open App from google calendar Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

The app I'm working on needs to be able to create events in a google Calendar and then when the user views these events it offers an option to return to the my app to view more information about it and the data related to it.

Using Calendar Provider I'm able to create the events and I store the Uri to the event for later use/removal but I haven't found a good way to open my app from these events.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a way to do this other than placing your url into the event's description and then registering for the intent corresponding to that url.

Comment: thanks buddy ... can you also help me with a code snippet to understand this better